# Remove period up to matched substring but do not remove if there is no period

Tags: regex, ruby

`.\s(expect([^.]+.))`

Above is matched even if there's no period in the sentence

e.g. `Avg. Number of Gardening Quotes You Can Expect To Compare`

How can I strictly capture only when sentence has period with `Expect` keyword next?

`Avg. Number of Gardening Quotes. Expect To Compare`

https://rubular.com/r/hW3IcDxZSjAVfb

^ In rubular... it should not match anything, but it is capturing and truncating

Comment: Typo: You need to escape the `.` to `\.`, if you really want to match a literal dot.  [See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/jhb82m/1).

Comment: Oh. Missed that. thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please explain why there should be no match in the second string. Also, does `"Avg."` have anything to do with it? Is it just the contents of the two capture groups you want, or do you want the entire match, and if so, what part of each of your example strings do you wish to match (if any)? Be sure to make any corrections to your regex that you become aware of. It may be easiest to address these questions by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I strictly capture only when sentence has period **with Expect keyword next**?

For capturing anything depending on what’s next (or before,) it comes to [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
#       ⇓⇓ THIS
(\.\s*)(?=expect)
```

[Rubular example](https://rubular.com/r/4DbwVlDf5pWhqJ).